# Unmount fails with: "failed to clean up smb mountpoint(s)"

Tags: macos, smb

I have mounted an SMB share and I want to disconnect, but CMD-E just dims the share disk symbol on the desktop but never completes.
System log says:

```
  förval    10:09:00.748510 +0100   lsd SecTranslocate: DiskArbitration callback: failed to clean up mountpoint(s) related to volume: /Volumes/myshare
```

What could be the reason?
How can it be avoided?

If I logout, the share is back in the desktop when I log in again.
To get rid of it, I have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is some program is still using files on the share.

You could see what programming is using files on your share by running the folling line from the command line:

```
lsof | grep "/Volumes/yourshare/"
```